# Why d3 removes data during second update

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I update my data (using d3) twice with exactly the same model.

During the first update I can see that data().enter() contains some elements and data().exit() is empty. That is understandable for me.

During second update (with the same model) data().enter() is empty (as I thought), but data().exit() is not empty and because of that it removes all the nodes during second update. This is what I don't understand.

Here is simplified code (and jsfiddle; look at the console):

```
// http://jsfiddle.net/24yqteo0/
// http://jsfiddle.net/6du29258/ - example with displaying some data

var model = {
    smth: 'test',
    rows: [
        {
            label: 'label1',
            series: [
                {
                    test: 'test1_1'
                },
                {
                    test: 'test1_2'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'label2',
            series: [
                {
                    test: 'test2'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
updateData(model);
console.log('// ------------- new update');
updateData(model);

function updateData(model) {
    var selection = svg.selectAll('g').data(model.rows);
    console.log('selection enter size: ' + selection.enter().size());

    var rows = selection.enter().append('g');

    var rowData = rows.append('g').selectAll('g')
    .data(function (d) {
        return d.series;
    });

    console.log('rowdata enter size: ' + rowData.enter().size());
    var seriesGroup = rowData.enter().append('g');

    console.log('rowdata exit size: ' + rowData.exit().size());
    rowData.exit().remove();

    console.log('selection exit size: ' + selection.exit().size());
    selection.exit().remove();
}
```

Comment: On general update patterns here is a good example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218

Comment: My model data is a bit nested, this causes the problems. I can't find the bug there though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is not helpful for debugging when you use just plain `g` elements for nested enters and exits.

I replaced the `seriesGroup` appends with `text` as follows [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/24yqteo0/1/):

```
var seriesGroup = rowData.enter()
    .append('text')
    .text(function (d) { return d.test; });
```

I quickly spotted the problem in you code. It is actually the first line of `updateData`

```
var selection = svg.selectAll('g').data(model.rows);
```

This selection includes *ALL* `g` elements, including nested ones. (console.log selection to confirm)
To prevent this behavior, you can add a more precise selector, such as `class`

```
var selection = svg.selectAll('g.row').data(model.rows);
```

and then `append`

```
var rows = selection.enter()
    .append('g')
    .classed('row', true);
```

Similarly for the second level:

```
var rowData = rows.append('g').selectAll('g.series')
```

and then

```
var seriesGroup = rowData.enter()
    .append('g')
    .classed('series', true);
```

[Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/24yqteo0/2/).

Hope this helps.